# Grid if box has specific class stop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a grid with a player, yellow box, and obstacles (`.ob`) and black boxes. I don't want the player to go in the obstacle squares when I click the 'UP' button.

I was thinking to check if the next class has `.ob` do not go there. Any suggestions?

```js
let moveCounter = 0;
var grid = document.getElementById("grid-box");

for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  square.className = 'square';
  square.id = 'square' + i;
  grid.appendChild(square);
}

var obstacles = [];

while (obstacles.length < 20) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random());
  if (obstacles.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    obstacles.push(randomIndex);

    var drawObstacle = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawObstacle).addClass("ob")
  }
}
var playerTwo = [];

while (playerTwo.length < 1) {
  var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random());

  if (playerTwo.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    playerTwo.push(randomIndex);

    var drawPtwo = document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex);
    $(drawPtwo).addClass("p-1")
  }
};

$('#button_up').on('click', function() {
  moveCounter += 1;

  $pOne = $('.p-1')
  var id = $pOne.attr('id')
  var idNumber = +id.slice(6);
  var idMove = idNumber - 10
  var idUpMove = 'square' + idMove;
  $pOne.removeClass('p-1');
  $('#' + idUpMove).addClass('p-1');
});
```

```css
#grid-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#grid-box > div.square {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.p-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.ob {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-box"></div>
<div class="move">
  <button id="button_up">UP</button><br>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

[jsFifddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frankie9119/gyu9f56e/54/)

Comment: You can use hasClass method if found `ob` then move to other until found white

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
$('#button_up').on('click', function() {
  moveCounter += 1;

  $pOne = $('.p-1')
  var id = $pOne.attr('id')
  var idNumber = +id.slice(6);
  var idMove = idNumber - 10
  var idUpMove = 'square' + idMove;
  if($('#' + idUpMove).hasClass('ob')){
      return false;
  }
  $pOne.removeClass('p-1');
  $('#' + idUpMove).addClass('p-1');
});
```

Here we check the next selected class having ".ob" class if its return true then we stop the process if it returns false then process continues

```
if($('#' + idUpMove).hasClass('ob')){
      return false;
  }
```

---

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zu7rghc8/1/)